# help for showing this Inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

$x\in l_\infty$

Definition:

$$p(x):=\limsup_{i\to\infty}x_i:=\inf_i(\sup_{j\geq i }x_k)$$
show that $p$ is sublinear. In other words:

1.$p(x+y)\leq p(x)+p(y)\quad\forall x,y\in l_\infty$

2.$p(\alpha x)=\alpha p(x)\quad\forall x\in l_\infty\quad\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{K}$

Comment: Since your in the space of bounded sequences the limit should always exist. 1 should then follow from the triangle inequality on numbers. 2 should follow from the usual properties of limits.

Comment: Number 2. is only required to hold for $\alpha \geqslant 0$. And it does not hold for $\alpha < 0$ in general. (And $\limsup$ only makes sense for real sequences, not complex, so $p$ is only defined on the real space.)

Comment: Tank you for the points

Comment: Please check if my arguments below in the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to prove $$p(x):l_{\infty}\to\mathbb{R}$$ is a sub-linear mapping. We $p(x)$ is denifed as

$$p(x):=\limsup_{i\to\infty} x_i$$

$x=(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty\in l_{\infty}$

I am going to use this definition of

$$\limsup_{i\to\infty} x_i:= \lim_{i\to\infty}\sup\{x_j :j\geq i \}$$

1. $p(x+y)\leq p(x)+ p(y)$

$$p(x+y):=\limsup_{i\to\infty} (x_i+y_i):= \lim_{i\to\infty}\sup\{x_j+y_j :j\geq i \}$$

using supreme of a sum is lower or equal than sum of the supremes, we have
  $$\lim_{i\to\infty}\sup\{x_j+y_j :j\geq i \}\leq \lim_{i\to\infty}(\sup\{x_j :j\geq i \}+\sup\{y_j:j\geq i\})=p(x)+p(y)$$

since we can split the limit of a sum into a sum of limits.

1. $\alpha p(x)=p(\alpha x)$ $\quad\forall \alpha\geq 0$

$$p(\alpha x):=\limsup_{i\to\infty} \alpha x_i:= \lim_{i\to\infty}\sup\{\alpha x_j :j\geq i \}$$

$\alpha$ will "get out" of $\sup$ since $\alpha\geq 0$  and "get out" of limit since constants can do it in limits. So  $\alpha p(x)=p(\alpha x)$ .